# Rails server keeps crashing without any logs when deployed to AWS with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3

So, I deployed my rails app to AWS using `Capistrano`, the API's are called using an iOS App written in swift 4.

When the iOS App is launched, it makes 4-5 API calls, to fetch and update data onto the rails App. When these calls are made individually using a REST Client they all succeed without any issues. But when they are made simultaneously in the background of the iOS App, the server stops responding after 2 or 3 are done successfully. Funnily, this works perfectly when the rails server is run on my local machine (MacBook Pro).

I still have no idea what causes the server to stop responding, I check the logs, it ends on the last API call where it stops responding

```
Started GET "/api/v1/trendings" for XX.XXX.XXX.XX at 2018-06-30 07:44:32 +0000
```

The last line of my log

Answer (score 0):

Please, give me more information about that error.
What server are you using? (i.e: nginx, puma, apache)
What OS on the server?
What http error code are returned by Rails app? (i.e: 401, 500 etc)

If you are using puma server, there is some problems while handling multiple requests from same origin [as described here](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1085).

Regards.